# Sql left join and show result

Tags: mysql, join

Welcome,

I have 2 tables `int_client` AND `int_client_bank`.

In first important columns: `client_id, firstname, lastname, country, email, status`.
In the second: `client_id, status`.

I need to display all records: `firstname, lastname, country, e-mail WHERE status='25'` of the first column (except those records where `client_id` occurs in the second table).
If `client_id` occurs in the second table is skipping statuses of the first column, and displays only `status='25'` in secound table.

Sb can help me?

edit:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, country, email, COALESCE(b.status, a.status) status
 FROM int_client a
 LEFT JOIN int_client_back b USING (client_id)
 WHERE 
  (b.status IS NULL and a.status='25')
  OR b.status IS NOT NULL;
```

This is good code, but i need show only records there have status='25' in column B, and if a.client_id != b.client_id, i need show records there have status='25' in column A

Sb, help?

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide sample data and desired results?  Your description is hard to follow.

Answer (score 0):

`LEFT JOIN` with `COALESCE()` should do:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, country, email, COALESCE(b.status, a.status) status
 FROM int_client a
 LEFT JOIN int_client_back b USING (client_id)
 WHERE 
  (b.status IS NULL and a.status='25')
  OR b.status IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

This select query should work:

```
SELECT t1.first_name,t1.last_name,t1.country,t1.email FROM int_client AS t1, int_client_bank AS t2
WHERE t1.client_id = t2.client_id AND t1.status = 25;
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the query which will do the trick for you.

```
SELECT client_id, firstname, lastname, country, email, status FROM int_client as ic LEFT JOIN int_client_back icb ON ic.client_id=icb.client_id WHERE ic.status=25
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want all records from `int_client` where status is "25".  However, if another status exists in `int_client_bank`, then you want to show that status.

```
select c.first_name, c.last_name, c.email, c.country,
       coalesce(cb.status, c.status)
from int_client c left join
     int_client_bank cb
     on cb.client_id = c.client_id
where c.status = 25;
```

Comment: if record int_client exist in table int_client_bank dont show status from int_client but int_client_bank

Comment: @DariuszRup . . . I think that is what this query does.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT firstname, lastname, country, email, 
a.status as status_a, b.status as status_b, if(b.status is NULL, a.status, b.status) as final_status
 FROM int_client a
 LEFT JOIN int_client_bank b USING (client_id)
 WHERE 
  if(b.status is NULL, a.status, b.status) = '25'
```